# Seeking birth record for Ellen/Elinor, wife of John Billington, who arrived on Mayflower?

Tags: united-states, birth-records, 17th-century, europe

What is known about the Mayflower passenger Ellen/Elinor Billington? Specifically, what was her maiden name and who were her parents?

She was the wife of John Billington and mother of Francis Billington. After John's death, she remarried to Gregory Armstrong.

See [here](http://www.themayflowersociety.com/about-the-pilgrims20/the-pilgrims) for background on the Mayflower.

Answer (score 5):

For anything having to do with the Mayflower passengers there is a veritable plethora of information available from the General Society of Mayflower Descendants. They have ambitious projects to document five generations down from every passenger as well as their origins. Many of their works are available in genealogical libraries. You should check what is available for John Billington.

I am a descendant of John Billington. John was that infamous first European executed in the New World for committing murder. The Plymouth Colony did not know the English common law concerning murder, and had to send a delegation to John Winthrop and the Massachusetts Bay Colony to get advice on what to do. This was a bit awkward as the two colonies were not particularly friendly.

Comment: The five generation book for John Billington is currently on sale for $20.00.

Comment: Thank you for the info on John. Does the 'veritable plethora of information' contain Elinor's maiden name or her parents? If so, would you include in your answer please?

Comment: Duncan, I don't have a copy of the book! Very sorry. I certainly would have included that information if I had it! Care to go in halvsies with me?